# WP <= 6.1.1 – Unauthenticated Blind SSRF via DNS Rebinding

Tags: wordpress, security, server-side-attacks

We are experiencing the “WP <= 6.1.1 – Unauthenticated Blind SSRF via DNS Rebinding” issue in WordPress version 6.1.1 on my website [OlxPraca.com](https://www.olxpraca.com/), it means that there is a security vulnerability in the software that allows an attacker to carry out a blind Server-Side Request Forgery (SSRF) attack using DNS rebinding techniques. This vulnerability can be exploited by an attacker to access internal systems or services that are normally protected from external access. Please tell me the possible solutions for this problem/error.
Thanks.

The blog I need help with is: [www.olxpraca.com](https://www.olxpraca.com/)

I have updated WordPress, themes, and plugins.